# How to open .CDF file in R

Tags: r, gis

I am trying to open some (fairly old) geographical data that was stored as "Compact Data Format". The main file extension is .CDF and there are ancillary files with the same name but .BIN .BXL .DCB and .STY extensions.

I was able to open the file using Caliper's Maptitude software but it would save me a lot of time to be able to open them with R.

`readnc` from RNetCDF didn't work and I couldn't install the affyio package (which has a `read.cdffile.list` function), but it could be that both of these packages deal with different kinds of "CDF" files.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I doubt that Caliper's CDF format is related to netCDF (which is what R packages RNetCDF and ncdf4)  will read

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried [this](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/makecdfenv/html/read.cdffile.html)? And do you have a file URL (say on Github) that you can share for us to try?

Comment: @RichPauloo unfortunately makecdfenv didn't work. The data is proprietary and I couldnt figure out how to export a small sample in the exact same data format

Comment: Try scripting Maptitude with python to do conversion in batch to a format OGR can read https://www.caliper.com/maptitude/extending-maptitude-in-python.htm